# Want a way to export blender animation which uses deform modifiers and drivers

Tags: animation, modifiers, export, drivers, unity

I've created a page flipping animation in blender using some simple key frames to rotate the plane 180 degrees and some modifiers with drivers so the movement is not entirely rigid. Two deform modifiers: one bend and one twist. [image]

The modifiers with drivers are setup like so:

[image]

My problem is that when I export this as an fbx file and open it in unity, it only animates the rotation, and not the modifiers.

[image]

From my (limited) understanding, there might be a way to bake the modifier drivers using shape keys. Is there a straightforward way to export this as a baked animation for use in unity, without redoing the whole animation in a different way? The animation doesn't need to be editable once exported.